# Primefaces ajaxStatus doesn't call start event

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have a search button which calls a method in my backing Bean via AJAX. When it's clicked, I'd like to show an animated loading icon, and for that I went for Primefaces' ajaxStatus. The element I put on facet "default" loads perfectly, but the other element in the facet "start" doesn't. Here's the code of the button (p:commandLink) and the ajaxStatus inside it:

```html
<p:commandLink id="buscarCEP" class="btn btn-default"
        style="vertical-align: text-bottom;" action="#{inscricaoController.setEndereco()}"
        process="alunoCEP @this" update="endereco" global="true">
        <p:ajaxStatus style="display:inline-block">
            <f:facet name="default">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="start">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh glyphicon-refresh-animate"></i>
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="complete">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
            </f:facet>
        </p:ajaxStatus>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;Buscar CEP
</p:commandLink>
```

Comment: I've never seen ajaxStatus be used as a child of commandLink. That might be the reason. Try with usong the normal onstart and oncomplete attributes of the commandLink to manipulate icons based on css

Comment: Or show/hide the different `<i/>`  tags..

Comment: You know that thing that sometimes happen to all of us programmers when something does not work and then suddenly it works like a charm? That happened now. Thank you for your help, but apparently it worked fine.